# How do I get the bulb holder off of the wire?

Tags: wiring, light, bulb, rewire

There are no screws. I've tried pulling and there's no budging! No obvious signs of anywhere I can put a screwdriver to pop it off. Even if I cut the wires and try to re-wire it, I'm still not sure the actual holder will come apart... Help!

[image: bottom of the light bulb holder]

[image: side profile of bulb holder]

[image: inside bulb holder]

Comment: Hello, welcome.  What are we looking at here?  Is this part of a lamp assembly?  What model?  And why do you need to remove the wires?  It would be helpful if you could edit more details into your question, and perhaps also pictures from other angles.

Comment: I tried uploading another photo but it wouldn't let me? It's unbranded from Ebay. I have made some lamp bases and need to either take the bulb holder off or the inline switch and plug. The plug is completely sealed though which is the issue I'm having because I can't do it like I did before. This is a photo of underneath the light bulb holder. (the lamp base only has a small hole in the bottom so need to thread the wire through it) .... Update - it has now let me upload some more photos!

Comment: Are you trying to save bulb holder?  Cut it off , or it twist apart.  Looks like you push on the taps on the side to open .

Comment: I need to keep it fairly intact as I will be selling them on as complete lamps. I've tried pressing the sides as I thought the same with no luck. I've unscrewed the rubber bits holding the wire in place but still no movement.

Comment: If you're intending to use many of these as components in a complete lamp you intend to sell, the best answer may be to find a more suitable component that's easier to disassemble.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like tabs need to be pushed, or screw driver lifts tab for release.

Comment: Maybe, but one can't assume that these are intended to come apart. They may well have non-reversible snap clips. Also, the wires are probably soldered in place. OP won't be able to re-sell them as UL listed if the wires are detached.